# Попытка разобраться в RSA. ed ≡ 1 (mod λ)

Tags: rsa

Пытаюсь разобраться с RSA.

> ed ≡ 1 (mod λ)

Где

> λ = НОК ( p-1;q-1)

Немогу понять как доказыватся этот момент. В литературе нахожу информацию, только что это выведено при помощи расширеного алгоритма Евклида и используюется для дальнейшего доказательства правдивости m^ed ≡ m mod n
Буду благодарна за линк или обьяснение, как имея m^ed ≡ m mod n, для любого m мы можем показать, что ed mod λ ≡ 1